# Probability Independence Question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I'm trying to understand the following question and solution:

> Let A be the event that it rains tomorrow and suppose $P(A) = 1/3$.  Also supposed that a fair coin is tossed; let B be the event it lands heads up.  We have $P(B)=1/2$.
>
> Now I ask what is $P(A|B)$?  Due to independence $P(A|B)=P(A)=1/3$.  The result of the coin toss had nothing to do with tomorrow's weather.
> Two events are independent if $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$

Now I have tried to recreate this problem so I can use the set theoretic definitions.  It was suggested that $P(\{(r,h)\}) = 1/6, P(\{(r,t)\}) = 1/6$ be chosen for $P(Rain_{tomorrow})$ if independence of a fair coin toss is assumed.  I'm having challenges understanding how this assumption is made.  Does anyone know?

$S = Rain \times CoinToss$, $|S| = |Rain| \times |CoinToss| = 2 \times 2$

$Rain_{tomorrow} = \{ (r,h), (r,t) \}$
$P(\{(r,h)\}) = 1/6, P(\{(r,t)\}) = 1/6, P(Rain_{tomorrow}) = 1/3$

$Heads_{tomorrow} = \{ (r,h), (\lnot r,h) \}$
$P(\{(r,h)\}) = 1/6, P(\{(\lnot r,h)\}) = 2/6, P(Heads_{tomorrow}) = 1/2$

$P(Rain_{tomorrow}|Heads_{tomorrow}) = P(Rain_{tomorrow} \cap Heads_{tomorrow})/P(Heads_{tomorrow}) = (1/6)/(1/2) = 2/6 = 1/3$

Now to check for independence:
$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$
$P(A \cap B) = P(\{(r,h\}) = 1/6$
$P(A)P(B) = (1/2) * (1/3) = 1/6$

So it would appear the events are independent.

Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: How are you computing your joint probabilities?  Surely $P(\{r,h\})$ the probability that it is raining AND my coin toss comes up $H$ is $\frac 13\times \frac 12=\frac 16$.  Where did you get $\frac 14$?

Comment: Note that your four probabilities, $\frac 14, \frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 14$, don't even sum to $1$.

Comment: There are only three probabilities mentioned, the fourth $(\lnot r, t)$ is not mentioned.

Comment: I agree, this makes no sense how you are supposedly calculating your probabilities.  It looks eerily like when you went and wrote $|S|=|\text{Rain}|\times |\text{Coin toss}|=2\times 2 = 4$ that you might have been talking about how the sample space has four elements in it and might be making the common but very incorrect assumption that those four elements in the sample space occur equally often.

Comment: Ok, but where do you get $\frac 14$ for $P(\{r,h\})$?  Clearly, that already violates independence.

Comment: Recall, $\Pr(A) = \dfrac{|A|}{|S|}$ is a valid approach to calculating probability of an event $A$ in a sample space $S$ if and only if the outcomes in $S$ are known to be equally likely to occur.  There are only two outcomes to a lottery, you win or you lose, however you don't win with probability $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @lulu I knew the probability of the coin coming up heads is $1/2$, so assigned equal probabilities to each in $\{(r,h), (\lnot r, h))\}$.  Maybe that was wrong

Comment: $(r,h),(r,t)$ will get equal probabilities... but to recognize that requires the assumption of independence and assuming the coin is fair.  $(r,h)$ and $(\neg r,h)$ will add up to $\frac{1}{2}$ but are not equal.

Comment: My main issue is the author to this question and solution just says the coin toss has nothing to do with the event that it rains.  I'm trying to find what this looks like using a sample space where the set theoretic definitions work.  Or if I'm approaching this wrong and should forget about the the set theory part.  For instance they mention independence definition, but do not show how it is calculated for the example.

Comment: You can't really *prove* independence here... In order to discuss this particular experiment mathematically we must make some sort of model describing the experiment and the only reasonable way to do so is to *assume independence* between the result of the coinflip and whether or not it rains.  Trying to prove independence with this would wind up being circular logic.  Without the independence assumption, being told $\Pr(\text{Rain})=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\Pr(\text{Heads})=\frac{1}{2}$ would not be enough information to find $\Pr(\{r,h\})$ by itself.

Comment: As for why we should be allowed to assume independence here?  From our collective human experience, we are quite certain from observation that flipping a coin has no effect on the weather.  Some more primitive tribal cultures may still believe that performing rain dances can bring the rain, but in the mathematical community we at least regard that as nonsense.  This can be supported by data, allowing us to assume it in calculations when modeling such a scenario.

Comment: As for "*they mention independence definition, but do not show how it is calculated for the example*" I will reiterate that they didn't calculate or prove independence, they assumed independence.  "*The result of the coin toss had nothing to do with tomorrow's weather*" is stated as though it were a fact, an assumption backed up by millennia of collective human experience.  As for how independence was *used*, independence is when $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$ which is also equivalent to $\Pr(A\mid B) = \Pr(A)$.  They used this second identity in the problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz I updated the equations based on your feedback and the numbers work out showing independence.  How did you know $(r,h),(r,t)$ would get equal probabilities under the assumption of independence?  Is it because a different event $\{h,t\}$ is assumed independent of $\{r, \lnot r\}$?  and that $\{h,t\}$ are equally likely?

Comment: $\{h,t\}$ is not an event here.  $\{(r,h),(r,t)\}$ (*the event that it rains*) is an event and is independent of the event $\{(r,h),(\neg r, h)\}$ (*the event that a head is flipped*)